# Can I run an antenna ground conductor along the dirt?

Tags: grounding, tv-antenna

I have a chimney mounted antenna and mast that I need to ground. It is about 20-30ft horizontally to the existing electrical service entrance ground rod, so I was planning on running a conductor down the chimney and across the dirt to this existing rod.

What is an appropriate conductor to use that I can "lightly bury" in the dirt next to the house? Or do I need to run the conductor across the exterior wall only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grounding conductors smaller than #6 require protection NEC250.120.C but yes it could be run along the wall at ground level.